# Skia Font Styles

Tags: c++, skia

I am using Skia to draw text on BlackBerry 10 platform.
I have trouble applying Condensed or Light styles to the font.

In Skia, it only has type enum for ***kNormal***, ***kBold***, ***kItalic***, and ***kBoldItalic*** styles.

*These Styles Works Well*

```
skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("Slate Pro", SkTypeface::kNormal);
skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("Slate Pro", SkTypeface::kBold);
skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("Slate Pro", SkTypeface::kItalic);
skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("Slate Pro", SkTypeface::kBoldItalic);
```

But I need to use the ***Condensed*** or ***Light*** styles of the Slate Pro font which is also built in the BB10 device.

I tried all those combination this and it caused a ***SIGSEGV***.

```
skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("SlateProLight", SkTypeface::kNormal);
skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("Slate Pro-Light", SkTypeface::kNormal);
skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("Slate Pro - Light", SkTypeface::kNormal);
skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("SlatePro Light", SkTypeface::kNormal);
skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("Slate Pro Condensed", SkTypeface::kNormal);
```

Sooooo, I tried another approach by trying to load the system fonts directly. But still, even though the Font file exists, the loadedTypeface is always NULL, can't figure out why.

```
QString loadedFont="/usr/fonts/font_repository/monotype/SlatePro-Light.ttf";
SkTypeface *loadedTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromFile(loadedFont.toUtf8().constData());

QFile targetFile(loadedFont);

if(targetFile.exists())
{
     if(loadedTypeface!=NULL)
     {
          skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromTypeface(loadedTypeface , SkTypeface::kNormal);
     }
     else //Fallback to Arial
     {
          skTypeface = SkTypeface::CreateFromName("Arial",SkTypeface::kNormal);
     }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to use the ***Condensed*** or ***Light*** styles of the font? Thank you

***Notes***
The list of Slate Pro ***ttf files*** embeded ***in BB10 file system***

***Located in*** `/usr/fonts/font_repository/monotype/`

```
SlatePro.ttf
SlatePro-MediumItalic.ttf
SlatePro-MediumCondensed.ttf
SlatePro-Medium.ttf
SlatePro-LightItalic.ttf
SlatePro-Light.ttf
SlatePro-Italic.ttf
SlatePro-Condensed.ttf
SlatePro-BoldItalic.ttf
SlatePro-BoldCondensed.ttf
SlatePro-Bold.ttf
```